# permission deined и вторая ошибка 'tuple' has no attribute 'write' после правки выдаёт ошибку my_file.close() innendationerror

Tags: python

Bыдаёт несколько ошибок:

- `my_file = open("loveeI.txt", "w")` пишет

  > permission denied
- > 'tuple' has no attribute 'write'

```
from random import randint
while True :
     my_file = open("loveeI.txt","w")    
     print(" Hi, my name is Robolove ") 
     print("Tell me two names ")
     name1 = input(" First  name - ")
     name2 = input(" Second name - ")

     my_file.write(name1)
     my_file.write(name2)

     x = randint(20,100)
     print (x,"%")
     if x > 70:
         print("UUUU I SMELL LOVE")
     else:
         print("You can try")

     if x > 50:
      print("It's your choice")

     else:
         print("Try again, I could say something wrong ")


     my_file.close()

      # This code was made for fun. Don't take it serious
```

Comment: Какая система? И еще код отформатирован ужасно, и в английском опечатки. Я исправлю.

Answer (score 1):

`PermissionDenied` выдает потому что слишком часто открывается файл и система блокирует доступ.
Чтобы ее исправить воспользуйтесь менеджером `with`

```
from random import randint
with open('loveeI.txt','w') as my_file:
    while True :
        print(" Hi, my name is Robolove ")
        print("Tell me two names ") 
        name1 = input(" First name - ")
        name2 = input(" Second name - ")
        my_file.write(name1)
        my_file.write(name2) 
        x = randint(20,100) 
        print (x,"%") 
        if x > 70: 
            print("UUUU I SMELL LOVE") 
        else: 
            print("You can try") 
        if x > 50: 
            print("It's your choice") 
        else: 
            print("Try again, I could say something wrong ")
```

Comment: вы абсолютно правильно написали по поводу `with`, но скажите пожалуйста вы получали ошибку `PermissionDenied` или нет ?

Comment: Я ее получал спустя некоторое время работы

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всем, ваша программа *не скончается* — ваш цикл *бесконечный*.
(Я напишу, как это исправить.)

Вы вероятно запустили вашу программу *снова*, пока ваша предыдущая (бесконечная) всё время непрерывно работала — с тем же самым файлом!

Потому ваша первая ошибка («permission denied»).

(Когда вы знаете как, окончите насильственно всё, что вы запускали, когда нет, просто сделайте, что пишу дальше.)

**Ни каких ошибок ваша программа не выдала для меня.** Но какие-то предложения:

1. Вместо

   ```
   my_file = open("loveeI.txt","w")
   ```

   используйте

   ```
   my_file = open("другое_имя.txt", "а")
   ```

   т.е. используйте какое-то другое имя (т.к. ваше первое заблокировано), и примените параметр `"a"` (append) вместо `"w"` (write), чтобы всякий раз не переписывать ваш выводной файл (а только добавить записи за его конец).

---

2. Вместо

   ```
   my_file.write(name1)
   my_file.write(name2)
   ```

   используйте

   ```
   my_file.write(name1 + "\n")         # "\n" - символ перехода на новую строку
   my_file.write(name2 + "\n")
   ```

   чтобы в выводном файле было всякое имя на своей строке — иначе всё будет только в одной.

---

3. Вместо

   ```
   if x > 50:
       print("It's your choice")

   else:
       print("Try again, I could say something wrong ")


   my_file.close()
   ```

   (всё кроме последней строки только для контекста) используйте

   ```
   if x > 50:
       print("It's your choice")

   else:
       print("Try again, I could say something wrong ")

   if name1 == "" and name2 == "":
       my_file.close()
       break                   # немедленный выход из цикла while True
   ```

   чтобы ваш бесконечный цикл, т.е. ваша игра, окончилась при нажатии только <kbd>Enter</kbd> для обоих имен.